# Exporting multiple json files to specific folder python

Tags: python, json, dataframe

My part of code is

```
    js_file = response.text
    filename = [x for x in df['col1']]
    for names in filename:
        with open(names, 'w') as outfile:
           json.dump(js_file,outfile)
```

What i need to do is to export to specific folder which doesn't exist and specify the extension of filenames

for an example for the extension:

- filename1.json
- filename2.json
- ... so on

I know it's already exported as json file but i need to know how to add the extension to multiple files and put files in specific folder that doesn't exist

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The following code can be used

```
import pathlib
import os
js_file = response.text
# expecting json filenames present in col1 like " 'filename1', 'filename2' "
filenames = df['col1']
parent_folder = "folder_name"
pathlib.Path(parent_folder).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
for names in filenames:
  json_file_name = os.path.join(parent_folder, names+".json" )
  with open(json_file_name, 'w') as outfile:
     json.dump(js_file,outfile)
```

Comment: I guess there's a problem with this code as it loops multiple times for each row and the output files are i.json, i.json.json, i.json.json and so on

Comment: Hi Peter, 
it was thought that there are distinct filenames in each row, like row1 contains filename1 and row2 contains filename2 and so on..  and it loop on that column. i.e., 'col1'
Also, there was a typo, which is edited.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me for whatever number of rows:

Lines here is same as rows

```
count = 0
for line in Lines:
    new_line = line.strip()
    response = requests.get(
        f"URL that include new_line"
    )
    for names in Lines:
        count += 1
        js_body = response.text
        json_file_name = os.path.join(directory, names)
        with open(json_file_name, 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(js_body,outfile)
        done = "Operation successfully completed"
        print(done,": ", count,", Filename: ", json_file_name)
    if count == len(Lines):
        break
print('finished successfully')
```